# Sphinx autodoc in Flask ImportError: no module named

Tags: python, flask, python-sphinx

I'm trying to set Sphinx autodoc for my Flask project.
Here is schema of my project:

```
Folder
|--docs
|   |--build
|   |--source
|       conf.py
|       index.rst
|       mod_ololo.rst
|       ....
|--flask_app
|   |--celery_worker.py
|   |--config.py
|   |--run.py
|   |--app
|       |--__init__.py
|       |--temp.py
|       |--mod_search
|       ....
|       |--mod_files
|           |--__init__.py
|           ....
```

and so on.

In conf.py I already set:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../.."))
```

I'm trying to add content of **temp.py** to my documentation. 
Here is content of **mod_ololo.rst**:

```
*******************************************
OLOLO module
*******************************************

Ololololo
======

.. automodule:: flask_app.app.temp
    :members:
```

And when I run `make html` for separate scripts - Sphinx autodoc works, but in case of my flask project it doesn't and shows me the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'config'
```

Where config is **config.py**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Purely a guess, but the `config` module that your sphinx builder isn't finding is probably the `config.py` module in your `flask_app` folder.  There's likely an `import config` statement somewhere in your `flask_app/app/temp.py` file, so when sphinx tries to run the `automodule` procedure on it, it gets a failure on that import.

From your directory structure it looks like your `flask_app` folder is not a python package, so you might have to add that folder rather than (or in addition to) its parent folder to the `path` in your `conf.py` file:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../flask_app'))
```

Also, you'll likely have to change your automodule statement in `mod_ololo.rst` not to reference `flask_app` as a package:

```
.. automodule:: app.temp
```

If you actually **do** intend to use `flask_app` as a package, then you need an `__init__.py` file in that folder, and your import statements within your project should be absolute from the top `flask_app` package, i.e.:

```
from flask_app import config
```

rather than

```
import config
```

Comment: Thank you, man. Changing sys.path on '../../flask_app' and 'app.temp' almost solved the problem. Now it shows error on reading *.csv and *.txt files that are laying in some folders, but I'll comment them on this time and  will try to find solution later.
Again thanks